# SQL command advice

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How would I make the `shipdate` year greater than 2013 in sql. Here is the code I have so far:

```
SELECT shipdate, COUNT(*)
  FROM dw.orderline
  GROUP BY shipdate
  ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: This isn't sufficient information to answer the question. You would at least need to provide a table definition

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
SELECT shipdate, COUNT(*) AS SHIP_COUNT
FROM dw.orderline
WHERE shipdate >= '01/01/2013'
GROUP BY shipdate;
```

EDIT:

As per your comments:

```
SELECT YEAR(shipdate), COUNT(*) AS SHIP_COUNT
FROM dw.orderline
WHERE YEAR(shipdate) > 2013
GROUP BY shipdate
```

EDIT 2:

For an Oracle based SQL:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM shipdate), COUNT(*) AS SHIP_COUNT
FROM dw.orderline
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM shipdate) > 2013
GROUP BY shipdate
```

See working example on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72488/2)

Comment: well... not on the end, but after the `FROM` clause and before the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: It would show everything after 01/01/2013 - that includes 02/01/2013, 03/01/2013, etc.. everything up until today. If you want to show eveything in 2013 and not 2014 then use 

WHERE shipdate >= '01/01/2013' AND shipdate < '01/01/2014'

Comment: Oh I see, just the year part of the date and everything after 2013. Updated answer, see above.

Comment: @TomBurbeck when I added your new code in oracle its telling me im missing an expression I tried added semi colon at then end but that still didn't work

Comment: Accidental comma after 'SHIP_COUNT' - try again without that.

Comment: @TomBurbeck  so try comma after it for example as SHIP_COUNT,  ? If so its still telling me that im missing an expression I tried running it witout a comma and it says that YEAR is an invalid identifier

Comment: Your question didn't say this was for Oracle SQL - thats different, see above.

Comment: Not a problem, mark the answer as correct if it helped you out :D

Answer (score 1):

Should it not be

```
SELECT 
    shipdate, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    dw.orderline
WHERE 
    Year(shipdate)>2013
GROUP BY 
    shipdate
```

Every date with year 2013 should be excluded as well. Or did I interpreted the question incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Correct Query:

```
SELECT shipdate, COUNT(*) ships_counter
  FROM dw.orderline
     WHERE shipdate > '01/01/2013'
        GROUP BY shipdate;
```